# Setting maxwidth on an input field in Bootstrap3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a table with a header, and I want to add inputs to the headers to allow people to filter on the table.  For instance:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Date Created&nbsp;<button id="btnToggleFilterDateCreated" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-filter"></i></button>
        <div class="dateRangePickers">
          <div class="input-group date" id="dateCreatedStartFilterDiv">
            <span class="input-group-addon datepickerbutton">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
            <input type="text" id="dateCreatedStartFilter" size="10" maxlength="10" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" /><br/>
            <span class="input-group-addon">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
              $('#dateCreatedStartFilterDiv').datetimepicker({ });
            });
          </script>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  <thead>
  <tbody>
    ...
  <tbody>
</table>
```

jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2u425cub/

But as soon as I apply the Bootstrap classes for formatting, my `maxwidth` gets ignored and the input blows the table columns out.  Is there a way to tell Bootstrap to respect the 10-character size limit for the input?

Comment: i'm not sure i do understand your question well, but i think you should try to reset the widths of your input and addons, see: http://jsfiddle.net/2u425cub/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not sure i do understand your question well, but i think you should try to reset the widths of your input and addons, see: http://jsfiddle.net/2u425cub/1

This can be don, by using the following CSS code:

```
.input-group .form-control, .input-group-addon, .input-group-btn {
    width:initial;
}
```